# How to add a for each loop in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have an issues in my code below.
In days and time i want to add a loop, it s because i want to be able to get multiple different operating hours row. I ll add a repeater in my custom field.
And for now it s allow me to get only one row.

```
<ul>
    
            <?php foreach($locations as $location) {
              
              $title = get_the_title($location);
    
              $address = '';
    
              $address .= get_field('address', $location) . '<br>';
              $address .= get_field('city', $location) . ', ';
              $address .= get_field('state', $location) . ', ';
              $address .= get_field('zip_code', $location); 
              $hours = get_field('days_open', $location);
              $phone = get_field('contact_number', $location);
              $email = get_field('contact_email', $location);
              ?>
              
              
    
              <li>
                <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
                <address><?php echo $address; ?></address>
                
                <?php if($phone) { ?>
                    <a href="tel:<?php echo $phone ?>"><?php echo $phone; ?></a>
                <?php }; ?>

                <?php if($email) { ?>
                    <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email ?>"><?php echo $email; ?></a>
                <?php }; ?>

              <?php
                if($hours && $hours[0]['days']
                ) {
                  echo $hours[0]['days'] . ': ';
                }
              ?>
              <?php
                if($hours && $hours[0]['times']
                ) {
                  echo $hours[0]['times'];
                }
              ?>
              </li>
    
              <?php
    
            }
          
            ?>
    
          </ul>
```

So i think my solution it s to add a foreach loop, can you help for that?
Thank you in advance cheers!

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are looking for?

```
 if(is_array($hours[0]['days'])){
     foreach($hours[0]['days'] as $day)
         {
             echo $day . ': ';
         }
  }
  if(is_array($hours[0]['times'])){
     foreach($hours[0]['times'] as $time)
         {
             echo $time . ': ';
         }
  }
```

Comment: HI user727728, thank you for your quick answer, but when I add the code in visual studio code, I get a syntax error.
Can you key me know if it s works for you?

Comment: Yes there were just couple of extra parenthesis, I have fixed it ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solutions it was :

```
<?php
              if(is_array($hours)){
                foreach($hours as $day)
                    {
                      echo $day['days'] . ': ';
                      echo $day['times'];
                      echo '<br />';
                    }
             } ?>
```